# Vba/Excel criando uma função no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando criar uma função, onde coloco uma vírgula depois de cada número ou palavra.
Segue o script do vba:

```vb
Public Function Virgula(Texto1, Texto2)
    Virgula = Texto1 & "," & Texto2 & ","
End function
```

É como concatenar.

Só consigo até dois, mas queria até 1000, se possível.

Comment: Você pode usar a função [`JOIN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) para juntar um array de strings usando um separador. Veja se esse exemplo em VB.NET o ajuda https://ideone.com/JYZ3Sy

Answer (score 0):

No VBA já existe uma função que acredito que faça o que está querendo, é a função join.
Ela recebe um array com as palavras que quer unir, e o segundo parâmetro é o delimitador.

No exemplo abaixo, a função está unindo os itens com uma vírgula entre eles:

```
Dim itens(0 To 2) As String
itens(0) = "Chave"
itens(1) = "Livro"
itens(3) = "Mouse"

Dim listaItens As String
listaItens = Join(itens, ",")
```

O resultado será "Chave, Livro, Mouse"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Faça isso dentro de uma função usando ParamArray pois a pergunta é sobre criar uma função com parâmetros variáveis. e.g. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/575525/vba-excel-criando-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-excel#comment1009947_575525